# Using a returned value as a function argument

Tags: python, function, selenium

I'm trying to use a value returned by one function as the argument value for another function - in this case, getting the page to open in selenium. However, outside of the function it does not recognise the value returned:

```
def discover(self, terms):
    self.open_browser()
    for term in terms:
        self.search(term)
        time.sleep(2)
        html = BeautifulSoup(self.driver.page_source, 'lxml')
        time.sleep(0.5)
        #self.scroll(html)
        cards = html.find_all('div', class_='styles__UserCardInformation-sc-f909fw-5 jEfkYy')
        #print(cards)
        time.sleep(0.5)
        for card in cards:
            self.open_profile(card)
            self.driver.get(user_profile_url)
```

The user_profile_url is returned by the open_profile function, ideal to be passed through the driver.get function. However, this doesn't work.

**open_profile function**

```
def open_profile(self, card):
    user = card.div.span.a.p.text
    user_link_suffix = card.div.span.a['href']
    user_profile_url = f'https://www.mixcloud.com{user_link_suffix}'
    print(user)
    return user_profile_url
```

Comment: you cannot return two values.

Comment: @Ramesh You can return more than one value

Comment: You never assigned the variable returned from `open_profile` in order to pass the assigned variable to `driver.get`

Comment: like this `return [output1,output2]`?

Comment: @Ramesh amongst few other ways, but more commonly it is done with implicit tuple - `return output1, output2`

Comment: @Ramesh You could do that or, more typically, *return output1, output2*. In a sense I suppose that's one object containing multiple values - in this case a tuple

Comment: @matszwecja There's nothing implicit about that. It's the `,`, not parentheses, that define a tuple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to assign the return value before using it

```
 def discover(self, terms):
self.open_browser()
for term in terms:
    self.search(term)
    time.sleep(2)
    html = BeautifulSoup(self.driver.page_source, 'lxml')
    time.sleep(0.5)
    #self.scroll(html)
    cards = html.find_all('div', class_='styles__UserCardInformation-sc-f909fw-5 jEfkYy')
    #print(cards)
    time.sleep(0.5)
    for card in cards:
        user_profile_url = self.open_profile(card)
        self.driver.get(user_profile_url)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can either assign the open_profile() to some variable and then pass that to get() or simply...

```
self.driver.get(self.open_profile(card))
```